# Copying a target table from HTML into Excel is not showing up

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, dom, web-scraping

Tried selecting the dropdowns from HTML file and tried copying the result table into Excel. But the below code coping some other text from HTML rather the table (which I want to populate to Excel).

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ele As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Dim commodity As String, iDate As String


    commodity = "MADHYA PRADESH"
    iDate = "REWA"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://hydro.imd.gov.in/hydrometweb/(S(3qitcijd521egpzhwqq3jk55))/DistrictRaifall.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("[value='" & commodity & "']").Selected = True
        .document.querySelector("[name=listItems]").FireEvent "onchange"
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.querySelector("[value='" & iDate & "']")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        If Not ele Is Nothing Then
            ele.Selected = True
            .document.querySelector("#GoBtn").Click
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Stop
        '.Quit


   Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object, hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object
   Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, tr As Object, td As Object

   Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

     Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
     Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

      y = 1   'Column A in Excel
      z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel

     Set doc = ie.document
     Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
     For Each tb In hTable

        Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each bb In hBody

            Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tr In hTR


                 Set hTD = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                 y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
                 For Each td In hTD
                   ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innerText
                   y = y + 1
                 Next td
                 DoEvents
                 z = z + 1
            Next tr
            Exit For
        Next bb
    Exit For
  Next tb
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try to find the HTML table by its ID and than try to loop through its rows to fetch the data may help you to fetch correct data. Ref: https://www.vba-market.com/vba-pull-html-table-to-excel-tool/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use clipboard and timed loops. There is scope for re-factoring which I will do later.

The page does an xhr POST request for the results so use dev tools which you may be able to replicate. It uses this url: http://hydro.imd.gov.in/hydrometweb/(S(yir33wzdcp5kls450czjmh45))/DistrictRaifall.aspx. See comment at end.

```
Option Explicit    
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, commodity As String, iDate As String, clipboard As Object, arr()

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    commodity = "MADHYA PRADESH"
    iDate = "REWA"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://hydro.imd.gov.in/hydrometweb/(S(3qitcijd521egpzhwqq3jk55))/DistrictRaifall.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("[value='" & commodity & "']").Selected = True
        .document.querySelector("[name=listItems]").FireEvent "onchange"

        arr = ElementFound(.document, "[value='" & iDate & "']")

        If Not arr(0) Then Exit Sub

        arr(1).Selected = True
        .document.querySelector("#GoBtn").Click

        arr = ElementFound(.document, "#GridId")

        If Not arr(0) Then Exit Sub

        clipboard.SetText arr(1).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ElementFound(ByRef document As Object, ByVal selector As String) As Variant
    Dim ele As Object, t As Date, arr(0 To 1)
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    t = Timer
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ele = document.querySelector(selector)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop While ele Is Nothing
    If Not ele Is Nothing Then
        arr(0) = True
    Else
        arr(0) = False
    End If
    Set arr(1) = ele
    ElementFound = arr
End Function
```

---

XHR:

The POST body includes parameters of

__EVENTTARGET: vbNullString

__EVENTARGUMENT: vbNullString

__LASTFOCUS: vbNullString

__VIEWSTATE: to be obtained. In my case at least obtaining this from a prior GET did not work

__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: 6C290774 '< static but can be obtained from prior GET

listItems: MADHYA PRADESH 'replace spaces with +

DistrictDropDownList: REWA

GoBtn: GO

Comment: Thanks again QHarr! It's working perfect. Great help!